# PowerShell XML Node Value from another file IF other Nodes -match

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have a script that's generating a xml file based on a .csv that's going to act as payload through a webservice (RESTapi).

The payload requires me to generate some GUIDs which is fine as long as I'm generating new ones. In order to successfully update data through the API i need to specify a GUID that already exist on each user in the receiving system.

So the first thing I do is a GET request to the system to export all users.
I then check users in my generated .xml file against the .xml from the GET request.

If users match, I want to extract the GUID that's existing in the export to my generated output. And this is where I'm stuck.

For example I've would match:

```
<CVs>
  <CV>
    <GUID></GUID>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <IDENTIFIER>aa</IDENTIFIER>
    </EMPLOYEE>
  </CV>
</CVs>
```

Against:

```
    <CV>
        <GUID>800b96cd-56e9-4587-a9db-41c2a4095d04</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>aa</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
    <CV>
        <GUID>a07ac517-c7d5-4766-89b6-9101260f6f53</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>bb</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
    <CV>
        <GUID>84d82720-3e06-4802-9206-69f25b2aa46d</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>cc</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
  </CVs>
```

And since "aa" is a match, I would like this output:

```
<CVs>
  <CV>
    <GUID>800b96cd-56e9-4587-a9db-41c2a4095d04</GUID>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <IDENTIFIER>aa</IDENTIFIER>
    </EMPLOYEE>
  </CV>
</CVs>
```

This is my working code for producing everything, except getting that GUID from another .xml if two nodes are matching.

```
$docTemplate = @'
  <CV>
    <GUID></GUID>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <IDENTIFIER>$($cert.Identifier)</IDENTIFIER>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <PAGE id="8">
  $($certs -join "`n")
    </PAGE>
  </CV>
'@

# Per-certificate template.
$entryTemplate = @'
    <RECORD>
      <GUID></GUID>
      <FIELD id="21">
        <DATA>
          <GUID></GUID>
          <VALUE>$($cert.Certificate)</VALUE>
        </DATA>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD id="36">
        <DATA><VALUE>$($cert.From)</VALUE></DATA>
      </FIELD> 
      <FIELD id="22">$($cert.ExpireDate)
        <DATA><VALUE>$($cert.to)</VALUE></DATA>
      </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
'@

$cvData = Import-Csv demo.csv -Delimiter ';' | Group-Object Identifier -ov grp | ForEach-Object {

  $certs = foreach ($cert in $_.Group) {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($entryTemplate)  
  }
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($docTemplate)
}

$rootTemplate = @'
<CVs>
$($cvData -join "`n")
</CVs>
'@
$output = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($rootTemplate) | Set-Content -LiteralPath 'cvoutput.xml'



#Add GUID
$xmlFile = '.\cvoutput.xml'
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFile

#Add Record GUID
foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.CVs.CV.PAGE.RECORD)
{
    [string]$element.GUID = New-Guid
}

#Check if Node exists (certifications require a GUID in the Cert Data Node)
foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.CVs.CV.PAGE.RECORD.FIELD | Where-Object  {$_.name -match "Certifications"}) {
  [string]$element.DATA.GUID = New-Guid
}


$xmlDoc.Save('cv-data.xml')
```

Comment: is your question how to get the GUIDs from the file?

Comment: Yeah, if the identifier and username node are matching I want to GUID from that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the gist correctly, you want to either create a new guid or use an existing guid that you get from a XML file containing a list of all existing users / guids.

Here's a minimal example on how you would read a file (I used a here string for the example instead), parse it as a list of user / guid, then check whether or not the user received is in the existing XML and get the corresponding GUID or create a new one.

.

```
$OutTemplate = @"
<CVs>
  <CV>
    <GUID>{0}</GUID>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <IDENTIFIER>{1}</IDENTIFIER>
    </EMPLOYEE>
  </CV>
</CVs>
"@

$AllUsers = @"
<CVS>
  <CV>
        <GUID>800b96cd-56e9-4587-a9db-41c2a4095d04</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>aa</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
    <CV>
        <GUID>a07ac517-c7d5-4766-89b6-9101260f6f53</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>bb</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
    <CV>
        <GUID>84d82720-3e06-4802-9206-69f25b2aa46d</GUID>
        <EMPLOYEE>
           <USERNAME>cc</USERNAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </CV>
  </CVS>
"@


#   From File 
#   $XML = [xml](Get-Content -Path 'PathToXML.xml' -Raw)

$XML = [xml]$Allusers
$Nodes = $XML.SelectNodes('//CV') | Select @{'Name' = 'EmployeeID' ; 'Expression' = { $_.EMPLOYEE.USERNAME } }, GUID

# Instead of a fixed array, you'd have your received users here.
$Employees = @('aa', 'csd', 'ee')

foreach ($emp in $employees) {
    $Guid = $Nodes | Where EmployeeID -eq ($emp) | Select -First 1
    if ($Guid -eq $null) {
        $Guid = New-Guid
        $Color = 'DarkMagenta'
    }
    else {
        $Color = 'Cyan'
        $Guid = $Guid.Guid
    }

    $OutElement = $OutTemplate -f $guid, $emp

    Write-Host $OutElement -ForegroundColor $Color

}
```

The important part of this example is the :

```
$Nodes = $XML.SelectNodes('//CV') | Select @{'Name' = 'EmployeeID' ; 'Expression' = { $_.EMPLOYEE.USERNAME } }, GUID
```

From there, you have your list of existing user GUID and you can process all records against it and decide whether to use an existing GUID or create a new one.

Comment: `$Nodes = $XML.SelectNodes('//CV') | Select @{'Name' = 'EmployeeID' ; 'Expression' = { $_.EMPLOYEE.USERNAME } }, GUID`

Sure did the trick! Thank you very much @Sage

Answer (score 0):

Just like **@sage-pourpre** suggests the:
`$Nodes = $XML.SelectNodes('//CV') | Select @{'Name' = 'EmployeeID' ; 'Expression' = { $_.EMPLOYEE.USERNAME } }, GUID`

With:
`foreach ($emp in $xmlDoc.CVs.CV ) {
  $Guid = $Nodes | Where EmployeeID -eq ($emp.EMPLOYEE.IDENTIFIER) | Select -First 1
  [string]$emp.GUID = $Guid.GUID
}`

Solves the problem.

Thank you!